# Jquery-ui, redirect to some page after you click on close button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how do i redirect after you click the close button?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog'
        });

    $('#opener').click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a callback for the `close` event in the following way as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog',
            close: function(ui, event) {
               $(this).dialog('close');
               // redirect over here.
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
location.href="url";
```

you can get the bindevent like this

// give your popupid below

```
$('div#popupid').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
     alert('closed');
     location.href="new url";
 });
```

Comment: @chicagoland, you can have a customized close event declared in jquery and do a location.href on click of that.

Comment: gov: where do i use `location.href="url";`

Comment: @chicagolang the close button might be a div or href right , you write your own click event or check  in the code...where they have declared that. Once you find that code , you can place your location.href code there.

Comment: gov: i would like to have my close event on the page and i did try modify the plugin and its work but i just wanted to know how can i do on close event without modifying the plugin.

Comment: @chicagoland , see my updated answer you can catch the dialog close event like that..it should definetly work...